# PyQt4 global shortcuts?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have an application that opens multiple children widgets as separate windows, something like this: window1 opens window 2 which opens window 3 (simplified form).

In the main window I have set CTRL+Q as the quit shortcut. Below is a stripped down example of the main class.

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.actionExit = QtGui.QAction(_('E&xit'),self)
        self.actionExit.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.actionExit.setStatusTip(_('Close application'))
        self.connect(self.actionExit, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), QtCore.SLOT('close()'))
```

Right now if I open the third child and push CTRL+Q nothing happens. Is there a way so that the children inherit the shortcut key for quit or to make the shortcut global or do I have to declare it in each of them?

Answer (score 12):

Here is what I have used in `__init__` function:
    `QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+Q"), self, self.close)`

It works smoothly!

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the [ShortcutContext](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qaction.html#shortcutContext-prop).

```
self.actionExit.setShortcutContext(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
```

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it's not working, even if the children widgets have the parent set as the MainWindow :\

Comment: Did you try `WindowShortcut` or `WidgetWithChildrenShortcut`?

Comment: I tried with all 4 options available for setShortcutContext but neither worked for the children.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just set a shortcut for your QAction directly:

```
self.actionExit.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+Q"))
```

The only difference between this example and your code is that the `Ctrl+Q` is first cast to `QtGui.QKeySequence`.